# LINQ To Objects - Join on empty list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have three individual Lists that are populated from different data sources, and now I want to join them in a LINQ statement for my final results.  However, it is entirely possible one of the Lists could be empty.  It appears I cannot just write a single LINQ statement to join any of these if the list is empty.

I've written up the following test.  The error I get is "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
// these colloections emulate the table structures and data
List<Agent> agents = new List<Agent>();
agents.Add(new Agent { AgentId = 1, ClientId = 11 });
agents.Add(new Agent { AgentId = 1, ClientId = 12 });
agents.Add(new Agent { AgentId = 1, ClientId = 13 });
agents.Add(new Agent { AgentId = 1, ClientId = 14 });
agents.Add(new Agent { AgentId = 2, ClientId = 21 });
agents.Add(new Agent { AgentId = 2, ClientId = 22 });
agents.Add(new Agent { AgentId = 3, ClientId = 31 });

List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
clients.Add(new Client { ClientId = 11, ClientName = "A Client 11", Status = "A" });
clients.Add(new Client { ClientId = 12, ClientName = "A Client 12", Status = "A" });
clients.Add(new Client { ClientId = 13, ClientName = "A Client 13", Status = "A" });
clients.Add(new Client { ClientId = 14, ClientName = "A Client 14", Status = "A" });
clients.Add(new Client { ClientId = 21, ClientName = "A Client 21", Status = "A" });
clients.Add(new Client { ClientId = 22, ClientName = "A Client 22", Status = "A" });
clients.Add(new Client { ClientId = 31, ClientName = "A Client 31", Status = "A" });

// Upon initilization, there are no records here.  Eventually, this "table" will be populated, 
// but only after the user has used the app for a while. If I populate this list, it works assuming
// the agent ID I'm looking for is in the collection.  But if it's not the join fails
List<ClientAdminFee> adminFees = new List<ClientAdminFee>();
//  adminFees.Add(new ClientAdminFee { AgentId = 1, ClientId = 11, AdminFee = 0.05m, EffectiveFrom = DateTime.Parse("2017-01-01") });
//  adminFees.Add(new ClientAdminFee { AgentId = 1, ClientId = 12, AdminFee = 0.05m, EffectiveFrom = DateTime.Parse("2017-01-01") });
//  adminFees.Add(new ClientAdminFee { AgentId = 1, ClientId = 13, AdminFee = 0.05m, EffectiveFrom = DateTime.Parse("2017-01-01") });
//  adminFees.Add(new ClientAdminFee { AgentId = 1, ClientId = 14, AdminFee = 0.05m, EffectiveFrom = DateTime.Parse("2017-01-01") });

var thisAgent = 1;
var theseAgents = agents.Where(x => x.AgentId == thisAgent).ToList();
var theseClients = clients.ToList();
var theseAdminFees = adminFees.Where(x => x.AgentId == thisAgent).ToList();

var final = (from ar in theseAgents
             join c in theseClients on ar.ClientId equals c.ClientId
             join caf in theseAdminFees on new { ar.AgentId, c.ClientId } equals new { caf.AgentId, caf.ClientId } into d
             from caf in d.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new ClientWithAdminFee
             {
                 AgentId = Convert.ToInt32(ar.AgentId),
                 ClientId = Convert.ToInt32(c.ClientId),
                 ClientName = c.ClientName,
                 Status = c.Status,
                 AdminFee = caf.AdminFee ?? 0.00m,
                 EffectiveDate = caf.EffectiveFrom ?? DateTime.Now
             }).ToList();

final.Dump();
```

As I said, if I uncomment the adminFees entries, and search for AgentId 1, it works.  However if I search for an agent that is not in that collection, I am unable to do the join at all.  So how can I write this so it works correctly if there are entries, as well as if there are no entries.

Comment: Look at Left Outer Join.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Code seem to explicitly ask for nulls with `DefaultIfEmpty` - so you'd better handle it. Side note : you can't get NRE on *empty list* as it is not null by itself...

Comment: I do LEFT OUTER JOINS all the time, and know how it works.  It doesn;t really help me out in this situation.  If I check for the collection to be a null before the LINQ statement, then I can;t very well write a LINQ statement that works in either case.

Comment: If you have LINQPad, and copy this code into it and run it, you'll see the issue.  Then if you uncomment the entries into the adminfees collection, and re-run it, you'll see that it works.  The application needs to be able to handle either case, and I'm not sure how to proceed with it.  Again, it's not a question of a LEFT OUTER JOIN since I do those all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var final = (from ar in theseAgents
                         join c in theseClients on ar.ClientId equals c.ClientId
                         join caf in theseAdminFees on new { ar.AgentId, c.ClientId } equals new { caf.AgentId, caf.ClientId } into d
                         from caf in d.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new ClientWithAdminFee
                         {
                             AgentId = Convert.ToInt32(ar.AgentId),
                             ClientId = Convert.ToInt32(c.ClientId),
                             ClientName = c.ClientName,
                             Status = c.Status,
                             AdminFee = caf != null ? (caf.AdminFee) : 0,
                             EffectiveDate = caf != null ? (caf.EffectiveFrom == null ? DateTime.Now : caf.EffectiveFrom) : DateTime.Now,
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanx, that mostly worked.  I had to change my underlying object (ClientWithAdminFee) to include Nullable properties, but it worked.  Thank you again, I knew it was probably something simple I was overlooking.